# Scroll not working only in middle of the screen

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am developing a shopping app. In one activity i have a item list in Table Layout. This table has a header row and two footer rows. I want to activate scroll only in the middle.

To achieve that i am having 3 TableLayouts. 1 containing only the header rows. 1 containing the main Item list and 1 contains the footer rows. Below is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.ahnaf.homemgt.Cart"
    android:columnCount="1"
    android:rowCount="5"
    >
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="HomeMGT" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3"
        >
        <TableRow
            android:minHeight="40dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/addItem"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_span="4"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                android:minHeight="0dp"
                android:minWidth="0dp"
                android:onClick="addItem"
                android:text="Add Item To Cart"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3"
        >
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:text="Qty"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:text="Price"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:text="Subtotal"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>


        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>


    <ScrollView>
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3"
            android:id="@+id/myTableLayout">

        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        >
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:text="Total"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/total"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:minHeight="40dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cashOut"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_span="4"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                android:minHeight="0dp"
                android:minWidth="0dp"
                android:onClick="addItem"
                android:text="Cash Out"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>


</GridLayout>
```

Initially everything looks ok but when i add too many items my scroll does not work. The last two row containing Cash out button and total textview disappears as well. what am i doing wrong here ?

*****************************Solved with the below code*******************

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/appBarLayout"
        android:columnCount="1"
        android:rowCount="5"
        >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3"
            >
            <TableRow
                android:minHeight="40dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/addItem"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_span="4"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                    android:minHeight="0dp"
                    android:minWidth="0dp"
                    android:onClick="addItem"
                    android:text="Add Item To Cart"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3"
            >
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:text="Name"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                    android:textAlignment="center"/>


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:text="Qty"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                    android:textAlignment="center"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:text="Price"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                    android:textAlignment="center"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:text="Subtotal"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                    android:textAlignment="center"/>


            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>


        <ScrollView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <!--<LinearLayout-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:orientation="vertical"-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/myLinearLayout">-->
                <TableLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3"
                    android:id="@+id/myTableLayout">

                </TableLayout>





            <!--</LinearLayout>-->
        </ScrollView>
    </GridLayout>

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:columnCount="1"
        android:rowCount="5"
        >
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            >
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    android:text="Total"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                    android:textAlignment="center"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/total"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="3"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                    android:textAlignment="center"/>


            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:minHeight="40dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/cashOut"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_span="4"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                    android:minHeight="0dp"
                    android:minWidth="0dp"
                    android:onClick="addItem"
                    android:text="Cash Out"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

    </GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if the code below works for you, I have wrapped everything in a Relative layout then divided you grid layout into two, the first one is at the top while the other one is anchored to the bottom of the screen.The top gridview has you scrollview which is scrollable and the 'footer' is sticky so that just the middle part scrolls:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/appBarLayout"
        android:columnCount="1"
        android:rowCount="5"
        >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3"
        >
        <TableRow
            android:minHeight="40dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/addItem"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_span="4"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                android:minHeight="0dp"
                android:minWidth="0dp"
                android:onClick="addItem"
                android:text="Add Item To Cart"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3"
        >
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:text="Qty"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:text="Price"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:text="Subtotal"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>


        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


           <!--/*Add your content here*/-->


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    </GridLayout>

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:columnCount="1"
        android:rowCount="5"
        >
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        >
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:text="Total"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/total"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:minHeight="40dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cashOut"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_span="4"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                android:minHeight="0dp"
                android:minWidth="0dp"
                android:onClick="addItem"
                android:text="Cash Out"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Now it is solved .. used a tablelayout instead of linear layout... thanks for leading me towards the right direction ..